# how to concatenate a string to a random string in trigger

Tags: sql, concatenation

this code generates a random string.
how to concatenate a string to this code??

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.insUser
   ON  dbo.UserProfile
AFTER Insert
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @UserId int
  SET @UserId = (SELECT max(UserId) FROM UserProfile)
UPDATE UserProfile set captcha =replace(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),8, 8),'-','') 
  WHERE UserId=@UserId
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually [`NEWID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/foof7014e60-96d5-457e-afc3-72b60ba20c0f.aspx) built in function return you unique identifier, wich can be converted to varchar using `CONVERT` function, so you can do some stuff with it.

```
replace(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),8, 8),'-','')
```

This code takes 8 characters starting from 8th position in generation newid, and replaces all `-` signs.

For concatenating string you can use built in function [`CONCAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) e.g:

```
SELECT CONCAT(N'some random string: ', REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 1, 10),'-',''))
```